# React-native android build failed with an exception

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I followed every single step in the react native documentation to set up a project with create-react-native.

`react-native init MobileProject`
`cd MobileProject && react-native run-android`

However, it seems like the build won't fetch resources online. I tried to change proxy, swapped repositories in `build.gradle` but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'MobileProject'.
>     Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
>      Required by:
>          project :
>     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
>     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
>     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
>     jcenter.bintray.com:443 failed to respond
>     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
>     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
>     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
>     dl.google.com:443 failed to respond

Comment: had you chance to fix this issue?  i got the same problem. :(

Comment: after days, i decided to switch to expo :(